# what does "it looks warmer" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> A: Which one of these sweaters do you like?
>
> B: I like the green one. It looks warmer.

Does it mean: Among the group of the sweaters, the green one seems to produce more warmth?

The dictionary lists *friendly* as a synonym for warm, could that be the case?

Comment: Sara, in all seriousness, how could a sweater **look** friendly? That is the second meaning......:)

Comment: Sweaters don't 'produce' warmth; they allow the wearer to retain the heat produced by their own body.

Comment: @ Lambie I thought maybe the green color can be described as friendly? :)

Comment: No, friendly means amicable. You need to use a proper dictionary and that confusion would not happen, I don't think.

Comment: It's a bit harsh to say "You need to use a proper dictionary"; I'm a native English speaker, and saying that a sweater gives a friendly vibe would be unusual, but not wrong, per se.

While the intent of the sentence is to say that the green one looks more comfortable, it could also be interpreted that the green sweater is more welcoming, and hence, friendlier.

Answer (score 6):

Colors can be described as cool or warm.

> They chose warm colors for the living room.

Warm colors have reds in them.  Cool colors have blues in them.

But here, in the context of a sweater, the sweater's ability to keep the wearer warm is most likely the subject, especially since green is not a warm color.

When we say that a sweater or coat "looks warm" we mean that it looks as though it will keep the wearer warm.

Comment: Don't wear that (ready-warmed?) sweater hanging up by the fire! I know it's cold in the garage, but there's a much warmer sweater out there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It could be a cotton sweater warming by the fire and a woolen sweater chilling in the garage.

Comment: Indeed. It's not that easy to come up with a credible context where a ***warm(er) sweater*** refers to its current temperature, rather than the fact that *it will keep the wearer warm(er).* But I think I managed to imply it there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But no sweater would "look" warmer in that sense, not unless it were smoldering and about to catch fire because it had been hung too close to the fire.  *Here, wear this one. It looks warmer. Don't mind the smoke*.

Comment: Ignoring actual temperature completely, if *colour* was the main contextually-relevant attribute, the "warmer" top could be an orange t-shirt, to be preferred over the "cooler-looking" [blue fox fur topcoat.](https://goo.gl/images/Cj9R7V)